# Enable autocomplete or intellisense in Atom editor for PHP

Tags: php, autocomplete, intellisense, atom-editor

I'm a first time user of Atom editor for my PHP code. Atom can autocomplete built-in functions of PHP. Is it possible to make the editor autocomplete my custom function that is written in a separate file?

function.php

```
<?php
function printSomething() {
   echo "Hello World";
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once "function.php";
printSomething(); // autocompleted by Atom editor while typing
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a text file in %userprofile%.atom called snippets.cson. In there you can add a snippet.

More about this: http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/

But then you need to think that you can use it later on other files as well. Otherwise you need to copy and paste.